# Delete a column within a list with several components in R

Tags: r

I want to delete the $MEgrey column of this list with 12 components
Thanks

Here is the code

```
MEList1 = moduleEigengenes(datExpr, colors = dynamicColors) str(MEList1)
```

List of 12

```
 $ eigengenes  :'data.frame':   15 obs. of  59 variables:
  ..$ MEbisque4        : num [1:15] -0.195 -0.424 -0.399 -0.315 0.296 ...
-0.237241 ...
  ..$ MEgrey           : num [1:15] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..$ MEgrey60         : num [1:15] -0.1556 -0.2304 -0.2371 -0.1066 -0.0272 ...
```

Comment: Try `MElist1$MEgrey <- NULL`

Comment: Do you mean *"delete the `$MEgrey` column from each `data.frame` in this list"*? The data representation is a little terse, but it looks like it's a list where at least one of the 12 items is a `data.frame`. If it's just the first element, then `MElist1[[1]]$MEgrey <- NULL` might work; if not, please provide a more [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by showing more of your sample data.

Comment: That worked perfectly!!! thanks a lot!!!!!!